# valgrind reporting errors and definitely lost when using realloc()

Tags: c, linux, valgrind, realloc

The following are two functions in which the first one tries to allocate and subsequently reallocate memory for an array of pointers depending on the count value.

The second function tries to concatenate the last string onwards to the first string from array of pointers.

The program takes in the number of strings and a pattern to be matched as command line arguments and calls the first function only when a matching pattern is found in the input string.

```
20  char **allocate_array_of_ptrs(char **str_array, /* pointer to the array of pointers */
21                      char *str,              /* pointer to the input string */
22                      int count)              /* count of matched strings */
23  {
24          char **temp = NULL;           /*      temporary pointer to realloc memory */
25
26          /* realloc based on count value */
27          temp = (char **)realloc(str_array, count * sizeof(char *));
28
29          int str_len = strlen(str);
30
31          /* if realloc is successful */
32          if (NULL != temp)
33          {
34                  str_array = temp;
35
36                  /* alloc memory for the string to be stored */
37                  temp[count - 1] = (char *)calloc((str_len + 1), sizeof(char));
38                  strcpy(temp[count - 1], str);
39          }
40
41          return str_array;
42  }
43
44  char **dmm_str_cat(char **str_array,          /* pointer to the array of pointers */
45                int count)                      /* count of matched strings */
46  {
47          int i;                                          /* iterator */
48          int total_str_len = 0;      /* total length when all strings put together */
49          int str_len_of_first;       /* string length of first string in the array */
50
51          if (count > 1)
52          {
53                  str_len_of_first = strlen(str_array[0]);
54
55                  for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
56                  {
57                          total_str_len += strlen(str_array[i]);
58                  }
59                  total_str_len += 1;
60
61              /* realloc memory to accomodate all matched strings onto first string */
62           str_array[0] = (char *)realloc(str_array[0], total_str_len * sizeof(char));
63
64                  /* clearing the new allocated bytes */
65                  for (i = (str_len_of_first + 1); i < total_str_len; i++)
66                  {
67                          str_array[0][i] = '\0';
68                  }
69
70                  /* concatenate from the last string onwards onto first string */
71                  for (i = count - 1; i > 0; i--)
72                  {
73                          strcat(str_array[0], str_array[i]);
74                  }
75          }
76
77          return str_array;
78  }
```

The problem is that when the code is run under valgrind, it reports the following messages when out of 3 strings, 2 strings do not match the pattern 'el'. Similar errors are reported for other combinations.

```
        Enter string 1 : matter

        Enter string 2 : matter

        Enter string 3 : jello

        Count of strings having matching pattern 'el' : 1
        The matching strings are :
                jello
==6244== Invalid read of size 8
==6244==    at 0x400A74: main (dmm_main.c:86)
==6244==  Address 0x4C33038 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==6244==    at 0x4A05809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:149)
==6244==    by 0x4A05883: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
==6244==    by 0x400AE9: allocate_array_of_ptrs (dmm_functions.c:27)
==6244==    by 0x4009B6: main (dmm_main.c:64)
==6244==
==6244== Invalid write of size 8
==6244==    at 0x400A89: main (dmm_main.c:87)
==6244==  Address 0x4C33038 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==6244==    at 0x4A05809: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:149)
==6244==    by 0x4A05883: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:306)
==6244==    by 0x400AE9: allocate_array_of_ptrs (dmm_functions.c:27)
==6244==    by 0x4009B6: main (dmm_main.c:64)
        The concatenated string is : jello==6244==
==6244== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 1)
==6244== malloc/free: in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==6244== malloc/free: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 14 bytes allocated.
==6244== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==6244== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible.
```

But when there are two strings that match the pattern whereas one doesn't match, then there are no errors/leaks reported by valgrind. When all strings match the pattern then definitely lost is being reported.

Comment: Thank you for the line numbers. (Edit: Aaaaaand Streppel removed them for some reason.... >_<)

Comment: @Izmaki Sorry, I didn't realize at the time that they would be helpful for the analysis of the question. I just made a roll-back to the first revision :-)

Comment: How are you calling function allocate_array_of_ptrs in your main ?
It almost seems like your str_array pointer is invalid for a realloc (like the address of a local variable for instance)

Comment: However if the lines referenced by Valgrind (86&87) are not in the posting they dn't help.o

Comment: @alk : 86 free(str_array[i]); 87 str_array[i] = NULL; /* this is inside a for loop running from 0 till (count - 1) and I am doing this only at the end of my program after the previous calls. */

Comment: @Doraj : 64 str_array = allocate_array_of_ptrs(str_array, str, count_match); /* here in main str_array is declared as (char **) and am using this to keep track of the reallocated memory from the allocate_array_of_ptrs function and print the strings inside main. */

Comment: sorry guys... the problem was in line 85 which contained the for loop for freeing. it had the wrong iterating value. please close this question. thanks for the help @alk regarding your line number comment.

Comment: @ChrisPetrus: So just ass your own answer and it accept it, to have the questin "closed".

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that you've an invalid read followed by an invalid write, I would bet that `str_array` passed to `allocate_array_of_ptrs` is not properly initialized-

Actually, message `0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd` makes me think that you're overpassing array's size but I can't be 100% sure without main.c code.